# VB.Net Assembly version problems

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, .net-assembly

One again I'd like to prove I am better at asking questions than answering them.

I am having horrendous problems with assembly versions with my application. I have two major ones that are causing grief which are the DYMO.DLS.Runtime.dll and MySQL.Data.

Quite some time ago I started using newer versions than i origionaly started with, and for months had no problems.

The references are correctly listed in the Applications Properties window, and the version numbers are correct for the ones in the bin folder (and the reference storage folder if you like).

Require Specific version is set to false (thou setting true does not fix the issue).

The major problem is, any builds (release or debug) throw exceptions because they are looking for old versions (the original versions), and now in the designer when saving forms the designer is throwing an exception that the tableadapermanager's connection property cannot be set because of a reference version mismatch (its asking for the new version, which IS referenced, and in the bin folder, etc).....

The list goes on. I cannot for the life of me find anywhere in any config file any reference to old versions, its just being a nightmare.

I have tried removing the references and re-referencing them, Iv deleted files, moved files, replaced files etc.

Is there somewhere else an Old version may be referenced? What is going on here??

This is driving me nuts, worse, every time I push updates to my clients it ends with me on the phone for hours fixing broken references. (Particularly Win 7 Machines, but I don't think that should matter) (FYI .NET 4 framework, VS2015, originally started in VS2012.)

Thank you all.

Comment: The designer also creates some code. Have you checked that for references to the old version? (You can get to that code by clicking `show all files` in the solution explorer.)

Comment: have a look in the vbproj file (using notepad) for any references to old version

Comment: 1st: Yes i have show all files, been through them, and the vbproj file refers correctly to the new versions. I have had a small win, i opened a previous version from backup, The issue was not there, apon reopening the new/current version, the design time errors have gone.....(no saves/changes made to either, figure that one out?!)

Comment: I am suspecting some designer / VS bug iv caused somehow.

Answer (score -1):

I would advise that you remove all the references to the offending assemblies from the project, move the assembly files to another folder (it's not 100% clear to me if you're keeping them in the project BIN folder - if you are then DEFINITELY move them to another!) and re-add them.  And of course, take a backup of the whole solution before you do ;)